# Вопрос по синтаксису Java при конкатенации.

Tags: java

Почему этот код работает корректно в Java? Пробовал в Eclipse и Intellij IDEA. Результат 8.

```
int a = 3, b = 5;    
System.out.println(a + + b);
```

Comment: Скорее вопрос, а почему он не должен работать корректно.

Comment: А вы что хотите сделать, конкатенацию строк или сложение чисел?

Answer (score 4):

Это не конкатенация, это же унарный плюс!

Попробуйте так:

```
int a = 100;
int b = +a;
System.out.println(b);
```

Ваш пример парсится как

```
System.out.println(a + (+b));
```

<s>Оператора `++` в Java нет.</s>

Поправка: оператор `++` есть, это **унарный** оператор постинкремента. Но в вашем случае с пробелом между плюсами компилятор видит именно два плюса: `+` и `+`, которые не «собираются» в один оператор `++`. Без пробела код бы просто не скомпилировался: `a ++ b` прочтётся как `(a++) b`, что, конечно, не является валидным выражением.

Инфиксного оператора `++` (то есть, с двумя операндами) в Java нет.

---

Конечно, унарный плюс не очень-то и нужен, он всё равно ничего не делает. Но он сохраняется для симметрии с унарным минусом (может помочь при автогенерации кода), и для совместимости по арифметическим фичам с C/C++.

Comment: "Оператора ++ в Java нет." Эм.. Что?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ой. И правда. // Исправил!

Comment: Кстати удивительно, но есть парочка способов применения унарного плюса в C. Ассерт на то что выражение арифметическое `#define CHECK_ARITHMETIC(x) (+(x))`. Преобразование типов  `char ch;
    short sh;
    int i;
    
    printf("%d %d %d",sizeof(ch),sizeof(sh),sizeof(i)); // output: 1 2 4
    
    printf("%d %d %d",sizeof(+ch),sizeof(+sh),sizeof(i)); // output: 4 4 4` и перевод в rvalue. `a=(+b)++; //не скомпилируется` и еще такое условие похоже всегда ложно `+(char)4 == (char)4`

Comment: @igumnov: Ого, круто. Унарный плюс превращает lvalue в rvalue.

Comment: @igumnov: А ещё, точно, арифметические операции «поднимают» тип операндов до `int`. А вот почему `+(char)4 == (char)4`, не соображу никак.

Comment: @Vlad Ошибся, sizeof там пропущен, тоже самое что и предыдущий пункт.

Comment: На инфиксный оператор его конструкция всё равно не тянет. Не знаю ни одного си-подобного языка, позволяющего пихать пробелы _внутрь_ операторов.

Comment: @igumnov, http://codepad.org/HEB9RUZk - равны они.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, я вроде бы это и пытался разъяснить. Уточню-ка ещё.

Comment: "постинкремента"? Префиксный там тоже был же...

Comment: Кстати, в BCPP 3.1 унарный плюс оставлял lvalue. Но да, должно превращаться в rvalue.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, был и префиксный. Но последовательность токенов `ident PLUSPLUS ident` наверняка парсится как `expression /* = ident PLUSPLUS */ ident`. Хотя конечно да, reduce/reduce-кофликт в грамматике :-D

Comment: Все, по результатам этого треда кресты надо переименовать из `C++` в `+C`

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имели в виду именно конкатенацию строк (к числам этот термин не применяется), то проще всего будет добавить `"" +`. Тогда все последующие `+` воспринимаются именно как операторы конкатенации, а не сложения.

```
System.out.println("" + 4 + 2 );
```

> 42

Ко всем аргументам будет применено преобразование в строку:

```
System.out.println("" + 4 + 2 + new Object()); // так можно
```

> 42java.lang.Object@350aac89

До первой операции со строкой это просто сложение:

```
System.out.println(4 + 2 + "" + 2);
```

> 62