# Почему нельзя 2 + + ++3?

Tags: java, инкремент

В [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/450140/181472) разобрались, что `2 + + 3` читается компилятором как `2 + (+3)`, то есть второй плюс — унарный.

В таком случае, почему не работает такое?

```
2 + + ++3
```

Как бы я это понимал, будучи компилятором:

```
2 + ( +( ++3 ) )
```

1. `( ++3 )` — выполнить инкремент и вернуть значение `4`
2. `( +4 )` — унарный плюс к `4`, вернуть `4`.
3. `2 + 4`, сложение, вернуть `6`.

Где ошибка в моем внутреннем компиляторе Java?

Кстати, `2 + + 3++` тоже не работает.

Comment: Не стоит такое писать из-за плохой читаемости :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: это не для читаемости, а для понимания языка. В рабочем коде, разумеется, такого никто не напишет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сам понял! Потому что инкременты нельзя применять к константам. Такое работает:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
System.out.println(+ a++ + + ++b);
```

Comment: Похожая тема затронута мною по этой ссылке http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000047-000-20-0. Правда она касается C++, но тем не менее показывает, как начинающих программистов может поставить в тупик "оператор" +++. :)